# Order by sensitive capital letter

Tags: mysql

I have some entries in my table:

```
id txt
1 phone
2 phone
3 phone
4 Phone
5 Phone
6 PHONE
7 phone
8 aaa
9 ZZZ
10 ééé
```

and I have this request

```sql
select * from table order upper(txt) collate utf8_bin
```

8 aaa
10 ééé
1 phone
2 phone
3 phone
4 Phone
5 Phone
6 PHONE
7 phone
9 ZZZ

I need to do an other order, which entry (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) was order a sensitive case, with the capital letter before

I want this result:

```
8 aaa
10 ééé
6 PHONE ===> CAPITAL
4 Phone ===> Capital
5 Phone ===> Capital
1 phone
2 phone
3 phone
7 phone
9 ZZZ
```

and also I need to use collate  collate utf8_bin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this as your ORDER BY clause.  This will first order all of the txt case insensitive, to get all names in order.  Then it will sort case sensitively (binary) in DESC order to put identical lower case names first.  The binary sorting would put capital letters before lowercase ones, that's why you need to use DESC.

```
ORDER BY txt, binary(txt) DESC
```